# When pressing on googleMap Marker on Android, 2 buttons appear in the bottom right corner, can I disable them?

Tags: android, google-maps, icons, google-maps-markers, markers

As the title suggests, I need to disable those buttons, I attached a screenshot of the app, so that you can see what I am talking about.
[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: post the relevant  click event please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `yourGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);`

Comment: thanks a lot, it works perfectly!! Was searching for a function, but on the marker object, didn't thought it was a map settings, my bad.